# threading function not executing in dockerfile

Tags: python, multithreading, docker, matplotlib, flask

If I execute this python code in my IDE, it works perfectly fine and updates the plot gets updated every time the check_time function returns True.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from threading import Thread
from flask import Flask, send_file
from config import *
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
from support_analysis import *
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

def update_plot():
    while True:

    if check_time(consistent=True):
        #print("script is updating")
        result = download_data()
        right_pred_rise, longest_rise, right_pred_fall, longest_fall \
            = print_metrics_over_time(df=result)

        ml_1pred, ml2_pred = get_latest_pred(result)

        result = result[['return', 'return_static_invest']]
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


        # Create the plot
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        result.plot(ax=ax)

        # Add the vertical lines
        plt.axvline(x=result.index[longest_rise[0]], color='green')
        plt.axvline(x=result.index[longest_rise[1]], color='green')
        plt.axvline(x=result.index[longest_fall[0]], color='red')
        plt.axvline(x=result.index[longest_fall[1]], color='red')

        # Add the red dot to the latest index
        latest_index = len(result) - 1
        ax.scatter(result.index[latest_index], ml_1pred, color='cornflowerblue')

        # Add the blue dot to the latest index
        ax.scatter(result.index[latest_index], ml2_pred, color='coral')

        plt.title(label='Bot vs buy and hold', fontweight='bold')
        plt.text(0.95, 0.01, timestamp, transform=plt.gcf().transFigure, ha='right', fontsize=8)

        plt.savefig('plot.png')

@app.route('/plot.png')
def plot():
    return send_file('plot.png', mimetype='image/png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start the update thread
    t = Thread(target=update_plot)
    t.start()

    # Run the web server
    app.run()
```

When deploying it via docker, the plot.png gets created and displayed on the port/plot.png url, but never updated, meaning that the thread that updates the function stops executing

this is the corresponding dockerfile (where i assume that the issue is)

```
FROM python:3.10

COPY main.py main.py
COPY config.py config.py
COPY support_analysis.py support_analysis.py
COPY numbers.pkl numbers.pkl
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt


RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN pip install gunicorn

EXPOSE 8000

# Run the WSGI server
CMD ["gunicorn"  , "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "main:app"]
```

Comment: Have you instrumented this at all, maybe even as little as adding `logging` or `print()` calls at various points in the flow?  Have you tried to see if the thread is exiting with an exception or otherwise stopping?

Comment: Yess i have. 
The threat is simply not executed

Comment: Are threads valid in Flask apps under gunicorn? A thread surely belongs within a single process and gunicorn can start multiple worker processes, so what happens if the thread is in a different process? Or if each process is running its own update thread and they are all writing PNGs to the same file on disk? Just asking - don't know myself.